# I need to know what is the name of this valve that is for my outdoor water line and where can I get a replacement?

Tags: water, outdoor, plumbing-fixture

[image][image] this piece is from the main water supply pipe

Comment: What's the matter with it?

Answer (score 2):

It probably does not matter what type valve it is. Looking at the part you show, I do not thing that you will be able to repair the existing valve, or be able to find parts to do a repair. I would replace the valve with a name brand, top quality, American made valve. You could use a gate, globe, or a full port ball valve. The part you show looks to be from a rising stem gate valve, but I could be wrong. I would have to see the whole valve to be sure.

Comment: The valve could be a stationary stem/rising gate valve.

Comment: I think ball valves (90 deg turn) are now used where brass gate valves used to be. They're the best choice for an on-off valve, such as a main supply cut-off, water heater cut-off, . . .  Ball valves are however not good for *metering* and I made the mistake of installing two fancy ball valves billed as "garden valves" (made in Italy) for outside faucets. This model is stiff and has a small handle so my wife can hardly turn it. I will have to fashion a small (wooden?) wrench to fit over the handle.  Adjustment of flow rate is difficult, but mostly we use it full on or all the way off.

Comment: Don't use a globe valve for a main shutoff.   It could significantly reduce the dynamic water pressure to the home.

Comment: All of the valves mentioned have their "pros and cons". Jim Stewart mentioned a few about ball valves.  I would add that if the ball valves  are not exercised (turned on/off occasionly) they will freeze up. Edwin mentioned that globe valves will reduce the flow rate, however they will be the least prone to freezing up when closed against a high incoming pressure, and gate valves after a short time will freeze up if closed against a high incoming pressure. So which ever you choose do not buy a cheap valve just to save money. I always tried to "but American" due to quality.